Main female character “The Hood”
I read a book/series about a female main character who acted in a very Robin Hood way, protecting those who couldn’t help themselves. She was referred to as 'The Hood'.
My problem is that I might be combining two books in my head. I remember her turning into a giant bird during fights and that she eventually gets put into a tournament.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Could this be Thief of Sorrows by Kristen M. Long?

What if Robin Hood was a woman who not only stole from the rich, but
killed them as well? Isolde Cotheran is anything but a damsel in need
of saving. Working through assuming the role of heir to Thornwood,
Isolde masquerades as the Hood, a vicious outlaw. The Hood leads a
cadre of thieves and assassins to steal and punish the lords and
ladies of Arnoria who do not heed her deadly warning: Abuse humans and
pay the price. In a world where hierarchy means life or death, humans
serve as slaves to Isolde’s kind, the Virya, a race of beings blessed
by the gods with the ability to transform into animals and control the
elements.


